# SQL query works in phpMyAdmin but not in php using PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo, escaping

I have a simple sql query that I would like to execute using PDO like so:

```
try {
    //connect to server
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';dbname='.DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    //check if username is valid
    $q="SELECT COUNT(*), first FROM users WHERE email='".$_POST['email']."'";
    echo $q;
    $stmt=$dbh->prepare($q);
    $stmt->execute();
    $f=$stmt->fetch();
    echo $f[0];
    echo $f[1];
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "There was an internal error resetting your password.";
  die();
}
```

The output for echo $q is to following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) first FROM users WHERE email='ahg44@cornell.edu'
```

When I copy and paste this into the SQL tab of phpmyadmin the query successfully returns the tuple I am looking for. However, it does not return anything in the php code.

Additionally, when I call: $stmt->debugDumpParams(); after the query, this is printed:

```
SQL: [64] SELECT COUNT(*), first FROM users WHERE email='ahg44@cornell.edu' Params: 0
```

At first I thought it was an error with the reading the POST variable so I hard coded:

```
$q="SELECT COUNT(*), first FROM users WHERE email='ahg44@cornell.edu'";
```

in place of the original query but this got me the same results.

Additionally, if I change the query to something simple like:

```
$q="SELECT COUNT(*), first FROM users
```

the code works fine.

The weird thing is the this query worked perfectly yesterday so I must have made a minor error while cleaning up my code today. I have a hunch the problem has something to do with escape characters but I've been searching online for a while and haven't found a solution.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although the PHP you pasted in your question looks correct, tt looks like you are actually missing a comma in the code that is executing..

This line:

```
SQL: [64] SELECT COUNT(*) first FROM users WHERE email='ahg44@cornell.edu'
```

shows no comma after `COUNT(*)`, so `first` is becoming the alias for the `COUNT(*)` column, rather than being selected as a separate column.

Comment: I actually had the comma in my original code and deleted it when pasting here by accident. Nice catch but it doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: Are you sure? Your output for `echo $q` also contains this error: `SELECT COUNT(*) first FROM users WHERE email='ahg44@cornell.edu'`

Comment: Oh you were right. Thanks. The echo $q now returns the query with the comma. But the fetch() still gives me nothing...

Answer (score 0):

You're using PDO incorrectly. You should be using prepared statements, like so:

```
$q = "SELECT COUNT(*), first FROM users WHERE email = ?";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare( $q);
$stmt->execute( array( $_POST['email']));
$f = $stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: hmmm...I subbed in your code and got the following from debugDumpParams().


SQL: [49] SELECT COUNT(*), first FROM users WHERE email = ? Params: 1 Key: Position #0: paramno=0 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2

Additionally, the fetch() still isn't giving me anything.